# How to loop slides and autoplay in custom javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js, slide

I'm a beginner in javascript. I downloaded a custom javacsript slide from this website:

https://www.cssscript.com/swiper-thumbnail-paginator/

Slide demo here: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/swiper-thumbnail-paginator/

I've also created a demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t4c1nb3g/

The file consists of 5 files, namely: index.html, style.css, debounce.js, script.js, slide.js

And it has 6 images.

Currently, there is no slide loop in the demo, I want the slide to start itself (autoplay) and repeat it again and again (looping).

How can I make it loop for the slide and start itself (autoplay)?

Below is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slide-wrapper">
    <ul class="slide">
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fkLR.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1Ri.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqYP.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/su1na.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZYry.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dXtQ.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-controls">
    <div class="arrow-nav">
      <button class="prev"></button>
    </div>
    <ul class="custom-controls">
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fkLR.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1Ri.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqYP.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/su1na.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZYry.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dXtQ.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="arrow-nav">
      <button class="next"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is the style.css file:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slide-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
}

.slide:hover {
  will-change: transform;
}

.slide li {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  opacity: .8;
  transform: scale(.8);
  transition: .4s;
}

.slide li.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

[data-control="slide"] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

[data-control="slide"] li a {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #FB5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999px;
  margin: 5px;
}

[data-control="slide"] li.active a, [data-control="slide"] li a:hover {
  background: #E54;
}

.custom-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custom-controls li {
  opacity: .8;
  transform: scale(.8);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-controls li.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.arrow-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}

.arrow-nav button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999 url('../img/arrow.svg') center center no-repeat;
  outline: none;
}

.arrow-nav button:hover {
  background: #333 url('../img/arrow.svg') center center no-repeat;
  transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}

.arrow-nav button.prev {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.wrap-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Below is the debounce.js file:

```
export default function debounce(callback, delay) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
      timer = null;
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

Below is the script.js file:

```
import SlideNav from './slide.js';

const slide = new SlideNav('.slide', '.slide-wrapper');
slide.init();
slide.addArrow('.prev', '.next');
slide.addControl('.custom-controls');
```

Below is the slide.js file:

```
import debounce from './debounce.js';

export class Slide {
  constructor(slide, wrapper) {
    this.slide = document.querySelector(slide)
    this.wrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper);
    this.dist = { finalPosition: 0, startX: 0, movement: 0 }
    this.activeClass = 'active';
    this.changeEvent = new Event('changeEvent');
  }

  transition(active) {
    this.slide.style.transition = active ? 'transform .3s' : '';
  }

  moveSlide(distX) {
    this.dist.movePosition = distX;
    this.slide.style.transform = `translate3d(${distX}px, 0, 0)`;
  }

  updatePosition(clientX) {
    this.dist.movement = (this.dist.startX - clientX) * 1.6;
    return this.dist.finalPosition - this.dist.movement;
  }

  onStart(event) {
    let movetype;
    if (event.type === 'mousedown') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.dist.startX = event.clientX;
      movetype = 'mousemove';
    } else {
      this.dist.startX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
      movetype = 'touchmove';
    }
    this.wrapper.addEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
    this.transition(false);
  }

  onMove(event) {
    const pointerPosition = (event.type === 'mousemove') ? event.clientX : event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
    const finalPosition = this.updatePosition(pointerPosition);
    this.moveSlide(finalPosition);
  }

  onEnd(event) {
    const movetype = (event.type === 'mouseup') ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove';
    this.wrapper.removeEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
    this.dist.finalPosition = this.dist.movePosition;
    this.transition(true);
    this.changeSlideOnEnd();
  }

  changeSlideOnEnd() {
    if (this.dist.movement > 120 && this.index.next !== undefined) {
      this.activeNextSlide();
    } else if (this.dist.movement < -120 && this.index.prev !== undefined) {
      this.activePrevSlide();
    } else {
      this.changeSlide(this.index.active);
    }
  }

  addSlideEvents() {
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onStart);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onStart);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onEnd);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', this.onEnd);
  }

  // Slides config

  slidePosition(slide) {
    const margin = (this.wrapper.offsetWidth - slide.offsetWidth) / 2;
    return -(slide.offsetLeft - margin);
  }

  slidesConfig() {
    this.slideArray = [...this.slide.children].map((element) => {
      const position = this.slidePosition(element);
      return { position, element };
    });
  }

  slidesIndexNav(index) {
    const last = this.slideArray.length - 1;
    this.index = {
      prev: index ? index - 1 : undefined,
      active: index,
      next: index === last ? undefined : index + 1,
    }
  }

  changeSlide(index) {
    const activeSlide = this.slideArray[index];
    this.moveSlide(activeSlide.position);
    this.slidesIndexNav(index);
    this.dist.finalPosition = activeSlide.position;
    this.changeActiveClass();
    this.wrapper.dispatchEvent(this.changeEvent);
  }

  changeActiveClass() {
    this.slideArray.forEach(item => item.element.classList.remove(this.activeClass));
    this.slideArray[this.index.active].element.classList.add(this.activeClass);
  }

  activePrevSlide() {
    if (this.index.prev !== undefined) this.changeSlide(this.index.prev);
  }

  activeNextSlide() {
    if (this.index.next !== undefined) this.changeSlide(this.index.next);
  }

  onResize() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.slidesConfig();
      this.changeSlide(this.index.active);
    }, 1000);
  }

  addResizeEvent() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  }

  bindEvents() {
    this.onStart = this.onStart.bind(this);
    this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);
    this.onEnd = this.onEnd.bind(this);

    this.activePrevSlide = this.activePrevSlide.bind(this);
    this.activeNextSlide = this.activeNextSlide.bind(this);

    this.onResize = debounce(this.onResize.bind(this), 200);
  }

  init() {
    this.bindEvents();
    this.transition(true);
    this.addSlideEvents();
    this.slidesConfig();
    this.addResizeEvent();
    this.changeSlide(0);
    return this;
  }
}

export default class SlideNav extends Slide {
  constructor(slide, wrapper) {
    super(slide, wrapper);
    this.bindControlEvents();
  }

  addArrow(prev, next) {
    this.prevElement = document.querySelector(prev);
    this.nextElement = document.querySelector(next);
    this.addArrowEvent();
  }

  addArrowEvent() {
    this.prevElement.addEventListener('click', this.activePrevSlide);
    this.nextElement.addEventListener('click', this.activeNextSlide);
  }

  createControl() {
    const control = document.createElement('ul');
    control.dataset.control = 'slide';
    this.slideArray.forEach((item, index) => {
      control.innerHTML += `<li><a href="#slide${index + 1}">${index + 1}</a></li>`;
    });
    this.wrapper.appendChild(control);
    return control;
  }

  eventControl(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.changeSlide(index);
    });
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('changeEvent', this.activeControlItem);
  }

  activeControlItem() {
    this.controlArray.forEach(item => item.classList.remove(this.activeClass));
    this.controlArray[this.index.active].classList.add(this.activeClass);
  }

  addControl(customControl) {
    this.control = document.querySelector(customControl) || this.createControl();
    this.controlArray = [...this.control.children];

    this.activeControlItem();
    this.controlArray.forEach(this.eventControl);
  }

  bindControlEvents() {
    this.eventControl = this.eventControl.bind(this);
    this.activeControlItem = this.activeControlItem.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Thank you very much,

best regards.

Franks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging your case on [Codepen](https://codepen.io), I finally figured it out.

Basically you need to know 2 changes that I made:

1. The first one is handling the edge cases:

   - When you're at the **end** and click **Next**, you should go to the **beginning**
   - When you're at the **beginning** and click **Previous**, you should go to the **end**
2. The 2nd aspect is making this slider autoplaying or looping.

---

### Now for the code

For the 1st change (the edge cases), modify in your code the methods `activePrevSlide` and `activeNextSlide` as the following:

```js
activePrevSlide() {
  if (this.index.prev !== undefined)
    this.changeSlide(this.index.prev);
  else
    this.changeSlide(this.slideArray.length - 1);
}

activeNextSlide() {
  if (this.index.next !== undefined)
    this.changeSlide(this.index.next);
  else
    this.changeSlide(0);
}
```

For the 2nd aspect, add at the end of `script.js`, this statement:

```js
setInterval(slide.activeNextSlide, 3000);
```

It will autoplay each 3 seconds (you can change it definitely).

---

### Finally, this is the full code, if you want to play here:

```js
function debounce(callback, delay) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      callback(...args);
      timer = null;
    }, delay);
  };
}
class Slide {
  constructor(slide, wrapper) {
    this.slide = document.querySelector(slide)
    this.wrapper = document.querySelector(wrapper);
    this.dist = { finalPosition: 0, startX: 0, movement: 0 }
    this.activeClass = 'active';
    this.changeEvent = new Event('changeEvent');
  }

  transition(active) {
    this.slide.style.transition = active ? 'transform .3s' : '';
  }

  moveSlide(distX) {
    this.dist.movePosition = distX;
    this.slide.style.transform = `translate3d(${distX}px, 0, 0)`;
  }

  updatePosition(clientX) {
    this.dist.movement = (this.dist.startX - clientX) * 1.6;
    return this.dist.finalPosition - this.dist.movement;
  }

  onStart(event) {
    let movetype;
    if (event.type === 'mousedown') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.dist.startX = event.clientX;
      movetype = 'mousemove';
    } else {
      this.dist.startX = event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
      movetype = 'touchmove';
    }
    this.wrapper.addEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
    this.transition(false);
  }

  onMove(event) {
    const pointerPosition = (event.type === 'mousemove') ? event.clientX : event.changedTouches[0].clientX;
    const finalPosition = this.updatePosition(pointerPosition);
    this.moveSlide(finalPosition);
  }

  onEnd(event) {
    const movetype = (event.type === 'mouseup') ? 'mousemove' : 'touchmove';
    this.wrapper.removeEventListener(movetype, this.onMove);
    this.dist.finalPosition = this.dist.movePosition;
    this.transition(true);
    this.changeSlideOnEnd();
  }

  changeSlideOnEnd() {
    if (this.dist.movement > 120 && this.index.next !== undefined) {
      this.activeNextSlide();
    } else if (this.dist.movement < -120 && this.index.prev !== undefined) {
      this.activePrevSlide();
    } else {
      this.changeSlide(this.index.active);
    }
  }

  addSlideEvents() {
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onStart);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onStart);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onEnd);
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('touchend', this.onEnd);
  }

  // Slides config

  slidePosition(slide) {
    const margin = (this.wrapper.offsetWidth - slide.offsetWidth) / 2;
    return -(slide.offsetLeft - margin);
  }

  slidesConfig() {
    this.slideArray = [...this.slide.children].map((element) => {
      const position = this.slidePosition(element);
      return { position, element };
    });
  }

  slidesIndexNav(index) {
    const last = this.slideArray.length - 1;
    this.index = {
      prev: index ? index - 1 : undefined,
      active: index,
      next: index === last ? undefined : index + 1,
    }
  }

  changeSlide(index) {
    const activeSlide = this.slideArray[index];
    this.moveSlide(activeSlide.position);
    this.slidesIndexNav(index);
    this.dist.finalPosition = activeSlide.position;
    this.changeActiveClass();
    this.wrapper.dispatchEvent(this.changeEvent);
  }

  changeActiveClass() {
    this.slideArray.forEach(item => item.element.classList.remove(this.activeClass));
    this.slideArray[this.index.active].element.classList.add(this.activeClass);
  }

  activePrevSlide() {
    if (this.index.prev !== undefined)
      this.changeSlide(this.index.prev);
    else
      this.changeSlide(this.slideArray.length - 1);
  }

  activeNextSlide() {
    if (this.index.next !== undefined)
      this.changeSlide(this.index.next);
    else
      this.changeSlide(0);
  }

  onResize() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.slidesConfig();
      this.changeSlide(this.index.active);
    }, 1000);
  }

  addResizeEvent() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
  }

  bindEvents() {
    this.onStart = this.onStart.bind(this);
    this.onMove = this.onMove.bind(this);
    this.onEnd = this.onEnd.bind(this);

    this.activePrevSlide = this.activePrevSlide.bind(this);
    this.activeNextSlide = this.activeNextSlide.bind(this);

    this.onResize = debounce(this.onResize.bind(this), 200);
  }

  init() {
    this.bindEvents();
    this.transition(true);
    this.addSlideEvents();
    this.slidesConfig();
    this.addResizeEvent();
    this.changeSlide(0);
    return this;
  }
}

class SlideNav extends Slide {
  constructor(slide, wrapper) {
    super(slide, wrapper);
    this.bindControlEvents();
  }

  addArrow(prev, next) {
    this.prevElement = document.querySelector(prev);
    this.nextElement = document.querySelector(next);
    this.addArrowEvent();
  }

  addArrowEvent() {
    this.prevElement.addEventListener('click', this.activePrevSlide);
    this.nextElement.addEventListener('click', this.activeNextSlide);
  }

  createControl() {
    const control = document.createElement('ul');
    control.dataset.control = 'slide';
    this.slideArray.forEach((item, index) => {
      control.innerHTML += `<li><a href="#slide${index + 1}">${index + 1}</a></li>`;
    });
    this.wrapper.appendChild(control);
    return control;
  }

  eventControl(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.changeSlide(index);
    });
    this.wrapper.addEventListener('changeEvent', this.activeControlItem);
  }

  activeControlItem() {
    this.controlArray.forEach(item => item.classList.remove(this.activeClass));
    this.controlArray[this.index.active].classList.add(this.activeClass);
  }

  addControl(customControl) {
    this.control = document.querySelector(customControl) || this.createControl();
    this.controlArray = [...this.control.children];

    this.activeControlItem();
    this.controlArray.forEach(this.eventControl);
  }

  bindControlEvents() {
    this.eventControl = this.eventControl.bind(this);
    this.activeControlItem = this.activeControlItem.bind(this);
  }
}


const slide = new SlideNav('.slide', '.slide-wrapper');
slide.init();
slide.addArrow('.prev', '.next');
slide.addControl('.custom-controls');

setInterval(slide.activeNextSlide, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slide-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: flex;
}

.slide:hover {
  will-change: transform;
}

.slide li {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  opacity: .8;
  transform: scale(.8);
  transition: .4s;
}

.slide li.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

[data-control="slide"] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

[data-control="slide"] li a {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #FB5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999px;
  margin: 5px;
}

[data-control="slide"] li.active a, [data-control="slide"] li a:hover {
  background: #E54;
}

.custom-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custom-controls li {
  opacity: .8;
  transform: scale(.8);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-controls li.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.arrow-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}

.arrow-nav button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999 url('../img/arrow.svg') center center no-repeat;
  outline: none;
}

.arrow-nav button:hover {
  background: #333 url('../img/arrow.svg') center center no-repeat;
  transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}

.arrow-nav button.prev {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.wrap-controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <ul class="slide">
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fkLR.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1Ri.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqYP.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/su1na.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZYry.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dXtQ.jpg" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrap-controls">
  <div class="arrow-nav">
    <button class="prev"></button>
  </div>
  <ul class="custom-controls">
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fkLR.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN1Ri.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqYP.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/su1na.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZYry.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dXtQ.jpg" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="arrow-nav">
    <button class="next"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regards